# Get array of ID from Firebase (DART/Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Is there any way to fetch data from Firebase with an array of documents.
Now I do this with loop. It works but maybe there is some more efficient way to fetch data? Members list can contain up to 10k users so create 10k requests seems wrong.

Many thanks!

```
ref = db.collection('users');

  Future<List<User>> fetchAllMembers({List<dynamic> members}) async {
    List<User> results = [];

    for (String userID in members) {
      await ref.document(userID).get().then((result) {
        results.add(User.fromMap(result.data, result.documentID));
      });
    }

    return results;
  }
```

Comment: `db.collection('users').get()` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Thank you for the response but maybe I do not explain my question clearly. I don't want to fetch all documents from the collection but only with specific IDs.

I have ```List<dynamic> = ['DSGSGSG', 'IBIOSCP3S, 'ASDUASDGU']```
i need to fetch them with one call to & dont use loop.

Comment: Do you use Firestore or Realtime Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values

```
userRef.where('id', 'in',
    [['DSGSGSG', 'IBIOSCP3S', 'ASDUASDGU']]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### SOLVED

So simple :). Working example below. Many thanks!

```
 final Firestore db = Firestore.instance;
 ref = db.collection('users');

List<dynamic> membersIDS = ['DSGSGSG', 'IBIOSCP3S', 'ASDUASDGU'];

  /// Fetch members list
  Future<List<User>> fetchAllMembers({List<dynamic> membersIDS}) async {

    /// With whereIn
    var result = await ref.where('uid', whereIn: members).getDocuments();
    var documents = result.documents.map((doc) => User.fromMap(doc.data, doc.documentID)).toList();
    return documents;

    /// With loop
    // List<User> results = [];
    // for (String userID in members) {
    //  await ref.document(userID).get().then((result) {
    //    results.add(User.fromMap(result.data, result.documentID));
    //  });
    // }
    // return results;
  }
```